# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when adding another object

Tags: java

I'm suffering on this exception. What's the problem on my code?
I just want to separate Person's duplicate name in another `ArrayList`

```
public class GlennTestMain
{

    static ArrayList<Person> ps;

    static ArrayList<Person> duplicates;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ps = new ArrayList<GlennTestMain.Person>();

        duplicates = new ArrayList<GlennTestMain.Person>();

        noDuplicate(new Person("Glenn", 123));
        noDuplicate(new Person("Glenn", 423));
        noDuplicate(new Person("Joe", 1423)); // error here


        System.out.println(ps.size());
        System.out.println(duplicates.size());
    }

    public static void noDuplicate(Person p1)
    {
        if(ps.size() != 0)
        {
            for(Person p : ps)
            {
                if(p.name.equals(p1.name))
                {
                    duplicates.add(p1);
                }
                else
                {
                    ps.add(p1);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ps.add(p1);
        }
    }

    static class Person
    {
        public Person(String n, int num)
        {
            this.name = n;
            this.age = num;
        }
        String name;
        int age;
    }



}
```

Here's the stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
at hk.com.GlennTestMain.noDuplicate(GlennTestMain.java:41)
at hk.com.GlennTestMain.main(GlennTestMain.java:30)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [concurrentModificationException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790856/concurrentmodificationexception)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot modify the `collection` you are iterating on. That might throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Though it might work sometimes, but it is not guaranteed to work everytime.

If you want to add, or remove something from your list, you need to use an `Iterator`, or `ListIterator` for your list. And use [`ListIterator#add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E)) method to add anything in your list. Even if in your `iterator`, if you try to use `List.add` or `List.remove`, you will get that exception, because that doesn't make any difference. You should use the methods of `iterator`.

See these posts to understand how to use it: -

- [Java : ConcurrentModificationException while iterating over list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596673/java-concurrentmodificationexception-while-iterating-over-list)
- [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/efficient-equivalent-for-removing-elements-while-iterating-the-collection)

Answer (score 7):

### Reason?

Iterators returned by [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is `fail-fast` in nature.

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and `listIterator` methods are `fail-fas`t: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

### Where does this iterator Come from while I am not using it?

For enhanced for loop for collections `Iterator` gets used so you can not call `add` method while you are iterating.

So your loop is same as below

```
for (Iterator<Entry> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ){
```

### What is the Solution Then ?

You can call [`iterator.add();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add%28E%29) and change loop based on iterator explicitly rather than implicitly.

```
    String inputWord = "john";
    ArrayList<String> wordlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    wordlist.add("rambo");
    wordlist.add("john");
    for (ListIterator<String> iterator = wordlist.listIterator(); iterator
            .hasNext();) {
        String z = iterator.next();
        if (z.equals(inputWord)) {
            iterator.add("3");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(wordlist.size());
```

### Now Where Can I Read more?

1. [The For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)
2. [ArrayList Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: does the CME only happens if the iterator is being used to iterate over the collection's elements and modify them?

Answer (score 1):

Acc. to [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html):

> if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.

You are tyring to add a `Person` object while iterating it using [Enhanced For loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685305/what-is-the-syntax-of-enhanced-for-loop-in-java).

You can do following modification:

```
boolean duplicateFound = false;
for(Person p : ps)
{
    if(p.name.equals(p1.name))
    {
        duplicates.add(p1);
        duplicateFound = true;
    }
}

if( ! duplicateFound)
{
    ps.add(p1);
}
```