# ConcurrentModificationException on iterating over ArrayList( see the results while iterating)

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

(I believe this is not a duplicate question!!). 
I am trying to iterate over a arrayList, do some manipulation and add elements to the same arrayList inside the for each loop.

I want to see the results while iterating.

I am ending up with ConcurrentModification Exception.

```
        for(String ex55 : firstListOfOptions)
    {
        Criteria crteria4 = session.createCriteria(Delays.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("programName", ex55));

        List<Delays> delaysList = crteria4.list();

        for(Delays dlys : delaysList)
        {
            if(!dlys.getProgramCalls().contentEquals(" "))
            {
            System.out.println(dlys.getProgramCalls());
            String[] resultSet = dlys.getProgramCalls().split(",");
            for(String rs : resultSet)
            {
                firstListOfOptions.add(rs);
            }
            }
        }


    }
```

How do I avoid this issue. Many thanks!

Comment: Modify and add object to a different list as you iterate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133688/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-when-adding-another-object

Comment: do you want to see the changes you've made to the list as you iterate? if not, you could create a copy of the initial list and iterate over that or alternatively construct a distinct new list for results

Comment: I do want to see the changes I made to the list as I am iterating.