# Error declaring an ArrayList of byte[] array copy returned deceptive error message saying to use iterator

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, clone

I am trying to copy an ArrayList of byte[] array within a builder constructor.  I want to copy arrayLst1 to arrayLst2.  I tried doing it with this code:

```
builder.arrayLst2.forEach(item->this.arrayLst1.add(item));
```

but I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

So Google lead me to Iterators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104692/how-to-avoid-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-when-iterating-through-an), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133688/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-when-adding-another-object) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm) so I tried this code (and other variations).

```
    for (Iterator itr = builder.arrayLst1.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
        this.arrayLst2.add(itr.next());
    }
```

The second line gives the error message "no suitable method found for add method."

I have tried along the lines of:

```
Iterator itr = this.arrayLst.iterator();        
builder.arrayLst2.forEach(item->itr.next()  );
```

but I can't figure out how to step through the first array1 and use iterator to add/copy to array2.

How do I clone one ArrayList byte[] to another?  I am sure there must be an easy solution but I can't find it.

Edit: The declaration error effectively meant that the arraylist wasn't declared.  Rather than say this, the compiler error message pointed to needing to use an iterator.

Comment: Can you add declaration of arrayLst1 and arrayLst2?

Comment: Hi.  I have declared both variables, I just haven't shown that in the code snippet.

Comment: Which is precisely why you're being asked to show them in the code snippet. Post a complete minimal example. You're using raw types everywhere in the posted code. Don't do that. Generics exist since Java 5. We're at Java 9.

Comment: I am still on the bottom end of the learning curve, and that includes knowing what and how to ask questions on this forum.  I really do appreciate the time people volunteer to help the helpless like me. I am learning as I go.   If it took until Java 5 to add generics, I probably don't need to know about them yet.  Right now all I am trying to do is learn how to clone an array.  That should be simple in any language.

Comment: Declarations are as follows:

Comment: @Zaki Anwar Hamdani I found an error in the declaration. It now looks like this: `    this.flagImgs = new ArrayList <>( this.flagImageFilenames.size());`  and the original command seems to work.  `    builder.flagImgs.forEach(item->this.flagImgs.add(item));`  The error message seems to have sent me on a wild goose chase.  And I can't get the mimi-markdown formating to work.

Comment: Please update your question with the wrong declaration and lets get it answered so that people facing similar issues in future can refer to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.arrayLst1 = new ArrayList<>(builder.arrayLst2);
```

or

```
this.arrayLst1 = new ArrayList<>();
this.arrayLst1.addAll(builder.arrayLst2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit to this answer belongs to #Zaki Anwar Hamdani.
I made an error in the declaration.

The following declaration works.

```
        this.flagImgs = new ArrayList <>( this.flagImageFilenames.size());
        builder.flagImgs.forEach(item->this.flagImgs.add(item));
```

The thing that stumped me was that the error messages did not hint at a problem  with the declaration.  The reference to Iterators sent me on a wild goose chase to nowhere.